# Rspec testing fail strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

Trying to get this one to pass for a while, not that familiar with Rspec, tried couple answers, and no luck yet, I have these two parameters being required on my controller as follow:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_back fallback_location: new_user_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password)
  end
end
```

and this is the rspec test that is giving me an issue:

```
  describe "GET #create" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :create
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end
```

here is the error that I am getting:

```
1) UsersController GET #create returns http success
     Failure/Error: params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password)

     ActionController::ParameterMissing:
       param is missing or the value is empty: user
```

I am looking at the rspec documentation right now, but any help would be appreciated it.

Comment: Your params should be of the form `{ :user => { :username => "", :password => "" } }`

Comment: Thanks Nandu, where exactly would I add the parameters? is it after the get method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
describe "POST #create" do
  it "returns http success" do
    post :create, params: { user: { username: "name", password: "password" } }
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
  end
end
```

It should be `post :create`, not `get :create`

Comment: Thanks Chivorn, I am getting a different error now, but I think this solution works. even with the get.

Comment: oh sorry, I don't think it's related anymore, but here:

Comment: 1) UsersController GET #create returns http success
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
       expected the response to have a success status code (2xx) but it was 302
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: @Lucky500 `302` means redirection `found`. This means your code runs well and this is also what you did your controller to redirect after `@user` is created. You can change the expect response to `expect(response).to have_http_status(:found)`  or `expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)` and see if it works.